# Flutter app is not running on different PC/MAC on both iOS and Android with same version of Flutter and Dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, compiler-errors, flutter-dependencies

I have a strange issue with my flutter APP. The issue is that I want to switch to a different PC/MAC, but I end up getting this error every time I want to run the app on both Windows and MAC.

The APP is running perfectly on 1 Mac that runs on both iOS and Android, but on another Mac it runs only on iOS, on Android it does not run.

Now I need to switch to another PC/MAC. Have tried both Mac and Windows and I still end up getting the same error on both different PCs.

The Flutter SDK version is the same as both on My MAC that it is running and on the NEW PC/MAC that it is not running.

I have tried to run: flutter clean and then flutter pub get but i still end up in the same situation.

On all PCs and Mac I have the same GRADLE installed, the one that the Project is requiring, but the same errors are happening on iOS so this is not related to gradle.

flutter --version:

```
Flutter 2.10.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c860cba910 (9 weeks ago) • 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
Engine • revision 57d3bac3dd
Tools • Dart 2.16.2 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

This is the error that I am facing on both the new Mac/Windows PC when I want to make a build on APK or iOS:

```
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Users/milotMango/Documents/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
      WidgetsBinding.instance.handlePopRoute;
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/milotMango/Documents/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/back_button_interceptor-6.0.0/lib/src/back_button_interceptor.dart:33:31: Error: Property 'handlePushRoute' cannot be accessed on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Users/milotMango/Documents/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
Script 'C:\Users\milotMango\Documents\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\milotMango\Documents\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           58.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

back_button_interceptor, this was the issue, even though I have not installed this package on pubspec.yaml, the flutter SDK downloaded from official website, was giving version 6.0.1, latest version, on the working pc my pc, it was 5.0.2, i installed it to pubspec.yaml and the problem is gone.